# JPOS IFB_NUMERIC vs IFB_LLNUM

Tags: iso8583, jpos

I'am using JPOS to pack iso8583 messages.

I am using a GenericPackager. In the definition of each field, whatvis the difference between :

IFB_NUMERIC vs IFB_LLNUM ?
IF_CHAR vs IF_LLCHAR ?

Thank you all for time.

Julien

Answer (score 1):

IFB_NUMERIC it's a fixed length field.
IFB_LLNUM it's a field whose length is represented by a byte in BCD.

IF_CHAR vs IF_LLCHAR is analogous but the length is in two decimal digits represented in ascii.